# If statements in loop (python)

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have 20 sectors and want to print my points per sector. With a bunch of if statements it looks like this:

```
if sector == 0:
    print(1)
if sector == 1:
    print(2)
if sector == 2:
    print(3)
...
if sector == 19:
    print(20)
```

How do I make this shorter and put it in a loop?

Comment: `print(sector+1)` ?

Answer (score 2):

I think that for what you want to do isn't necessary to use a for loop, this would be more suitable for executing some code over each element of a list of values. Note that for every sector you print the sector value + 1, so just `print(sector + 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

(while loop)
maybe something like this?:

```
sector = 0
while sector < 20:
    sector += 1
    print(sector)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using...

```
for x in range(0,yourUpperLimit):
      if sector==x
            print (x+1)
```

...would suffice if you are not going to include case specific code lines but I am not sure why would you need something like this. Can't you just use `print(sector+1)` instead?